# Router not working in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I am using BrowserRouter of react through which I want to navigate between pages. Initially there are four images in a page, and after clicking on one image, the image opens up in the screen. There is a back button below that image, which navigates the user back to the first screen with four images.

The code is like this

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import $ from 'jquery';
import {FirstPage} from './FirstPage.js';
import {BrowserRouter,Route,Router} from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
    }

    render(){
      return(
        <div>
          <BrowserRouter>
            <Route path="/" component={FirstPage}><FirstPage/></Route>
          </BrowserRouter>
        </div>
        )
    }
  }

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('container'));
```

FirstPage.js

```
class FirstPage extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state={
        list:[],
        images:[],
        isClicked:false
      }
      this.loadImages=this.loadImages.bind(this);
      this.loadOne=this.loadOne.bind(this);
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        window.addEventListener('load',this.loadImages);
   }

   loadImages(){ 
      console.log("load");
      var that=this;
      $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:'https://demo0813639.mockable.io/getPanos',
        datatype:'jsonp',
        success:function(result){
          var images=that.state.images;
          for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++){
            that.state.images.push({"pano":result[i].pano,"name":result[i].name});
          }
          that.setState({
            images:images
         })
        }

      })
   }

   loadOne(pano){
    this.setState({
      isClicked:true,
      imageUrl:pano
    })
  }

  render(){
    var list=this.state.list;

    if(this.state.isClicked===false){
        list=this.state.images.map((result)=>{
          //console.log(result.name);
        return(<div className="box">
                <div className="label">{result.name}</div>
                  <img src={result.pano} className="image col-md-3" onClick={this.loadOne.bind(this,result.pano)}/>   
              </div>
              )

       })
    }
    else{
      list.push(<Panorama imageUrl={this.state.imageUrl}/>)
    }

    return <div>{list}</div>;

    }
  }


module.exports={
  FirstPage:FirstPage
}
```

Panorama.js

```
import 'aframe';
import 'aframe-particle-system-component';
import {Entity, Scene} from 'aframe-react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

class Panorama extends React.Component{
    render(){
      return( 
        <div>
        <div className="pano">
          <Scene>
            <a-assets position="5 5 5">
              <img id="myImage" src={this.props.imageUrl} crossorigin="anonymous"/>
            </a-assets>
              <a-sky src="#myImage"></a-sky>
          </Scene>
          </div>
           <div className="goback"><Link to="/">Go back</Link></div>
          </div>
        )
    }
  }

module.exports={
  Panorama:Panorama
}
```

There aren't any errors for the above code, but it doesn't work too. The version of react router is v4. What is wrong above?

Comment: I don't believe the Route component should have the FirstPage component within it like "<Route path="/" component={FirstPage}><FirstPage/></Route>" but instead like <Route path="/" component={FirstPage} />

Comment: with that also, it doesn't work @Dream_Cap

Comment: Also I notice that you push directly to the state of images which I think is a bad practice in React. Maybe try declaring an array in a variable, and then setting the state with the array?

Comment: Yes that's a good suggestion I will do that

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you aren't really taking advantage of React Router here. The reason why the `<Link/>` doesn't do anything is because you're technically still on the same page as your image box, as you're not moving to another path, therefore the link would not trigger a path change.

I've created a quick example on how you can get past this issue. Of course it's not an exact replica of your project but it gives you an idea of how you can solve this issue.

=== Explanation

**Main App**

Our Main app consists of two routes. One for selecting an image and the other for viewing an image.

**View Image**

This displays an image that was sent across by the First Page component. This is one way to do it but you could also store images and active image in App Component and send it down to this child component so that you don't have to keep the image url in the parameter. (OR you could use Redux or some other global state manager).

**First Page**

We list a series of images via a simple array and keep an active index of the select image. We map these to the view via buttons and trigger an event once they have been clicked on which sets the active image and redirect flag that will redirect the user to the `image/:id` route with the image url.

*Of course, your loading of images can be improved but that's out of scope for this question.*

View working version here: https://codesandbox.io/s/pY2LyzAEr

=== Source

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Router, Redirect, Switch, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

// *-------------------------
// | First Page
// *-------------------------
class FirstPage extends React.Component{
  state = {
    currentActive: null,
    redirect: false,
    images: ['https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/12/22/10/04/lion-577104__340.jpg', 'http://www.yosemite.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Merced-Lake-back-of-Half-Dome_Kenny-Karst.jpg', 'http://www.japan-guide.com/g9/3060_12.jpg', 'https://cache-graphicslib.viator.com/graphicslib/thumbs674x446/3675/SITours/hong-kong-island-half-day-tour-in-hong-kong-114439.jpg']
  }
  viewImage = (evt) => {
    this.setState({
      currentActive: evt.target.dataset.image,
      redirect: true
    })
  }
  render(){
    return this.state.redirect 
      ? <Redirect to={`/image/${btoa(this.state.images[this.state.currentActive])}`} />
      : (
        <div>
          {this.state.images.map((image, index) => {
            return <button key={index} data-image={index} onClick={this.viewImage}>View Image {index + 1}</button>
          })}
        </div>
      )
  }
}

// *-------------------------
// | View Image Component
// *-------------------------
const ViewImage = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <img src={`${atob(props.match.params.id)}`} />
      <div><Link to="/">Back</Link></div>
    </div>
  )
}

// *-------------------------
// | Main App.JS
// *-------------------------
class App extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={FirstPage}/>
            <Route path="/image/:id" component={ViewImage}/>
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: This is a great code.Thanks. With my code, how can I pass {this.state.imageUrl} to the redirect link? If I do it your way, with $, it doesn't work.